# Scala: using value field to implement a trait method

Tags: scala, traits

I tried to do something like this in Scala

```
trait A { 
  def foo(i: Int): Int 
}

class B(val foo: Int => Int = _ + 1) extends A
```

But somewhat surprisingly I got this error from the compiler:

```
error: class B needs to be abstract, since method foo in trait A of type (i: Int)Int is not defined
   class B(val foo: Int => Int = _ + 1) extends A
```

And this didn't work either with the same error:

```
class C extends A { 
  val foo: Int => Int = _ + 1 
}
```

However this (obviously) worked:

```
class D(val bar: Int => Int = _ + 1) extends A { 
  def foo(i: Int): Int = bar(i) 
}

scala> (new D).foo(5)
res1: Int = 6
```

So the question is, why is Scala treating `def foo(i: Int): Int = ...` differently than `val foo: Int => Int = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, `def foo(i: Int): Int` defined in the trait: is a function which takes an integer as input and **returns an integer as the output**.

Where as, `val foo: Int => Int = _ + 1` defined in the class: is a function, **which returns a function.** That's the key point, you have not implemented the one from trait. The foo in the class B is returning a function and the returned function takes an integer as input and provided an integer in the output.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However sometimes it would be nice to be able sugar-coat my `D` class into something which looks like `B`..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an embarrassingly simple solution to my problem. All I had to do was to change my trait into this:

```
trait A { def foo: Int => Int }
```

And now it works as desired:

```
class B(val foo: Int => Int = _ + 1) extends A

scala> (new B).foo(6)
res3: Int = 7
```

Comment: I did not suggest that in my answer, as my thinking was, you do not want to modify the original trait. Getting used to "the function as first class object" concept is difficult at first but once you get the concept its pretty much like everything else.